# Pyinstaller Question about icons and writing to bundled files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.6.8 and Linux Ubuntu
I have an icon.ico image, and i want to embed it into the exe file in Pyinstaller. 
I have tried

```
pyinstaller -F -i= 'icon.ico' main.py and 

pyinstaller -F --icon= 'icon.ico:.' main.py
```

i tried all sorts of ways and i cant get it to work...

I basically have a tkinter app that i want to make an exe from...and i have created a png file turned it into icon and try to load it, but i am not sure it can be done,....is there a way to assign image.ico to apps? or change them, i know there is a way from the .desktop ...how do software do it that you download?

This is the internal code i am using:

```
import os, sys
from con import * # this is just a configuration file that has g='play' in it.
import subprocess



def resource_path(relative_path):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS # for --onefile
        # bundle_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(sys.executable)) # for --onedir
    else:
        bundle_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    return os.path.join(bundle_dir, relative_path)


resource_path('data/bitbud.ico')


basedir = getattr(sys, "_MEIPASS", os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
file=os.path.join(basedir, 'data/bell.mp3')
file2=os.path.join(basedir, 'data/testfile2.txt')
file3=os.path.join(basedir, 'data/bitbud.ico')

f=open('testfile1','w')
f.write('This has worked')
f.close()

f=open(file2,'a')
f.write('append also works')
f.close()

#if 'play' == g:

try:
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/cvlc',file],timeout=6)
except:
    pass

f1=open(file2,'r')
f=open('testfile3','w')
readit='The app has inside it:' +f1.read()
f.write(readit)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Comment: better to separate second question from this one if not it will be difficult for others to search in SO

Comment: I assume, that the reason you want to add an icon is, that the generated executable is using that icon on the desktop instead of a default icon.
Am I right?

You want this to work for Linux I assume?

Please confirm and adapt your question

Comment: The exe that is generated is using a generic icon...so i created a png one turned it to ico, and tried to load on to the exe using pyinstaller....is there another way to load an icon to the exe? in Linux Ubuntu yes

Comment: If you open the `.spec` file and go to the BUNDLE section at the bottom, you can try manually adding the icon file names there. Or you can see if the way you've been trying to add the icon is being added there.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJhCyC9Wivg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some line for you :D

1. Get file in bundled

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS # for --onefile
        # bundle_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(sys.executable)) # for --onedir
    else:
        bundle_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))

    return path.join(bundle_dir, relative_path)

---
resource_path('assets/file.jpg')
```

2. Edit `some.spec` file after run `Pyinstaller` first time, add params like below:

```
a = Analysis(
             ...
             datas=[('path/to/file.jpg', 'assets')]
             ...
...
exe = EXE(
          ...
          icon='path/to/icon.ico')
```

Comment: I am using Linux, this is ok ??

Comment: Hi please check my full code and video i put the code in my Question and video below